# Erro "Unknown: Failed opening required" ao seguir manual do slimphp

Tags: php, webserver, slimframework

Estou testando o Slim Framework em uma máquina com *Windows 10*, já nas primeira instruções recebi o erro:

```
Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'public\public/index.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in Unknown on line 0
```

Pesquisei em outras threads relacionadas e vi que pode ser algo com permissões mas já dei permissão master tanto no diretório do PHP quanto no diretório do projeto.

Segue minhas configurações:

- Local da pasta:

  ```
  C:/php
  ```
- Local do projeto:

  ```
  D:\git\slim-saa
  ```
- Versão do PHP:

  > PHP 7.1.12 (cli) (built: Nov 23 2017 04:21:28) ( ZTS MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015) x6 4 ) Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies

Projeto no [GitHub](https://github.com/getJv/slim-saa).

Estou seguindo exatamente o [manual inicial do Slim](https://www.slimframework.com/) e levanto o servidor embutido com o comando:

```
php -S localhost:8080 -t public public/index.php
```

Executado na raiz (pasta slim-saa)

Alguém pode me dar uma luz sobre como contornar esta situação?

Comment: Não deve ser permissão, isso ta parecendo mais um apontamento errado, provavelmente 'public\public/index.php', essa barra não ta trocada ?

Comment: PS: Clonei seu projeto, dei 'chmod -R 777 .' (permissões totais), rodei o composer e o projeto abri normalmente e funcionou.

Comment: Oi  @AnthraxisBR, sim... provavelmente funcionou pq vc esta em ambiente linux. mesmo alterando a barra continua o problema aqui.
<code>
Listening on http://localhost:8080
Document root is D:\git\slim-saa\public
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
[Fri Nov 24 10:01:56 2017] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[Fri Nov 24 10:01:56 2017] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required 'D:\git\slim-saa\public\public/index.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in Unknown on line 0
</code>

Comment: Veja que ele esta chamando public/public. ja testei varias combinações e os arquivos não ficam acessíveis.

Comment: ja tentou todar com um bash pra ver se ele funciona ?

Comment: E o slimphp precisas do  'libapache2-mod-php7.1'  e 'php7.1-mcrypt' instalados e ativos

Comment: que saco, não consegui. Vou aprender a usar o docker aqui e tentar resolver isso por ele. Muito obrigado mesmo pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui executar sem erros removendo o public do comando:

O site do Slim Framework diz para executar assim:

*$ cd [my-app-name]; php -S localhost:8080 -t public public/index.php*

Eu obtive sucesso executando assim:

**$ cd [my-app-name]; php -S localhost:8080 -t public index.php**

Comment: Você quer dizer assim `$ cd [my-app-name]; php -S localhost:8080 -t public/index.php`? Pois os dois comando na sua resposta estão identicos

Comment: Fiz a correção na minha resposta. Ao invés de public public/index ou public/index, a forma que funcionou foi public index.php